# Не работает css media screen

Tags: html, css, экран

Есть шапка для мобильного меню

```
.mobile_menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Медиа запрос

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px){

    .mobile_menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Работает, но если я изменю размер экрана на 979px и меньше запрос перестает работать в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: наверно проблема в meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" ...я не увидел этой строки в вашем коде

Comment: Оказывается что так спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прошу добавить в части `head` вашего сайта мета-тег

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Более подробное инфо. [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)